# How to use platform dependent .ini file to set FString console variables in UE4

Tags: unreal-engine4, ini

I want to set my console variable ( FString ) in platform dependent .ini file. In the `game\Config\Switch\SwitchDeviceProfiles.ini` I added:
`+CVars=MyUrl="http://string"`

When I display this variable in the console I get this:
`""http://string""` ( redundant quotes ).

Is there a possibility to set FString ( or maybe I should change the type of the variable? ) console variable to not have redundant quotes?
I use UE4.27

Answer (score 0):

So my mistake was in incorrect quotes placement.

This is a wrong way: `+CVars=MyUrl="http://string"`

This is the correct way: `+CVars="MyUrl=http://string"`